# Javascript - addClass() on hover not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

### html

```
<ul class="navBarExtended">
   <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

### css

```
.onHover{
text-decoration: underline;
 }
```

### javascript

```
$("ul.navBarExtended li a").hover(
    function(){
        $(this).addClass("onHover");
    },
    function(){
        $(this).removeClass("onHover");
 });
```

I'm trying to add 'onHover' class on to the element specifically a link, but it seems to be not working..so where you think the problem can be?

Comment: Make sure you have included jQuery.

Comment: Could you fork a jsfiddle with the example not working?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A better solution may be to use the [`:hover` pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/%3ahover) like so:

```
ul.navBarExtended li a:hover {
   text-decoration: underline;
}
```

However, your original code does seem to work (assuming you have set the default CSS for an `a` element to have no underline): http://jsfiddle.net/jaypeagi/wSG4s/

It's also worth noting that in your code, if you put the script tag before the HTML containing the `a` elements, it will not work ([see here](http://jsbin.com/ikaxeb/2)). This is because when the script runs, the elements do not exist. Consider making your code run on the [JQuery document ready event](http://api.jquery.com/ready). [Example here](http://jsbin.com/ikaxeb/3).

Comment: actually I want to add more complex styles so I need a little bit of javascript, its just that I included the most basic style in the question..

Comment: You can still perform an awful lot of styling using `:hover`. I'd recommend this if it is at all possible. Added some extra details for your original answer anyway though. Just in case!

Comment: Perhaps you could include more in a JS fiddle? Do you definitely have JQuery referenced in your code?

Comment: Its also worth noting that in your code, if you put the script tag before the html containing the `a` elements, it will not work. (see here http://jsbin.com/ikaxeb/2/)
This is because when the script runs, the elements do not exist. Consider making your code run on the JQuery document ready event: http://api.jquery.com/ready/.
Example here: http://jsbin.com/ikaxeb/3/

Comment: Please provide more code then. Since the given code does actually work.

Comment: got it!! thanks a lot! needed to add $(function  () { }); in javascript.

Comment: Added solution to the original answer for future reference.

Answer (score 3):

I think that's because by default `a` tags already have that `text-decoration`. Just add extra css to set it to none by default:

```
ul.navBarExtended li a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

But you should really just use a CSS class to manage the hover (if possible), by adding:

```
ul.navBarExtended li a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```